# PhotoShop alternative for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, image-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to Photoshop or Paint.NET](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3690/linux-alternative-to-photoshop-or-paint-net)

Hello. I am working in Ubuntu. I want to do some editing and drawing. On Windows I was using Adobe PhotoShop like software. Now I want to know which are the software available  for doing this. Also, is there any default software for drawing an image?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3690/linux-alternative-to-photoshop-or-paint-net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gimp or GNU Image Manipulation Program is the best alternative for photoshop in linux.

[image]

http://www.gimp.org

[Krita](http://krita.org/) (no longer a part of koffice) is also good:

[image]

You can also use [CinePaint](http://www.cinepaint.org/more/)

[image]

Comment: also you have Inkscape, very good application.

Comment: GIMP could not open or render `.TIFF` open layer. thats must be `.PSD`

Answer (score 2):

[Gimp](http://gimp.org) is the software for image manipulation. With Ubuntu you have many options such as krita, Inkscape etc.

```
sudo apt-get install gimp
```