# Are there any Ubuntu-based equivalents of Corel Draw, PageMaker, PhotoShop and Quark Express

Tags: software-recommendation

Are there any Ubuntu based application for the below listed softwares.

- Corel Draw - latest version
- PageMaker - Latest version
- Photoshop - Latest version
- Quark Express - latest version

Comment: Are you aware that PageMaker was discontinued in 2004? "latest version" is a bit ironic in this case. Also, it's not clear whether you want applications with similar functionality (there are some), want to run the mentioned applications on Ubuntu (possible, but...) or want to be able to open files created by the mentioned applications using their counterparts from Ubuntu

Comment: I wanted to know applications with similar functionality written for ubuntu. Any latest and stable working application would be good for get started.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/3690/alternative-to-photoshop-or-paint-net && http://askubuntu.com/questions/27670/photoshop-alternative-for-ubuntu

Comment: @nitstorm - but the answers you linked to only answer 25% of the OP's question :)

Answer (score 17):

Photoshop is a raster graphic editor. Ubuntu has **Gimp** and **Krita**

[image: Gimp]

PageMaker and QuarkXPress are both desktop publishing applications. It's interesting you mentioned those because Adobe InDesign is currently a clear leader among commercial applications in this area. Open-source equivalents are **Scribus**, **KWord** and (to some extent) **Lyx**

[image: Scribus]

CorelDraw is a vector editor. In Ubuntu, **Inkscape** provides similar functionality.

[image: Inkscape]

Answer (score 2):

These are the best alternatives to the softwares you have listed above:

1) CorelDraw - Inkscape, Xara Xtreme and Scribus (for desktop publishing only)

2) Pagemaker - Scribus, Lucidpress and Spring Publisher

3) Photoshop - GIMP, Krita, CinePaint and Pinta

4) Quark Express - Same alternatives as Pagemaker and probably CorelDraw too.

Source: I manage a website which publishes free and open source alternatives to commercial softwares so I have to research about lot of softwares. You can check it [here](http://www.opensourcealternative.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to add MyPaint as an alternative to Gimp and Krita for raster painting.
And though a bit dated at this point Xara Extreme is an alternative to Inkscape for Vector Graphics. Still perfectly usable for most tasks.

Answer (score 0):

... Scribus for page layout. Not exactly pagemaker though, probably better. Not sure how it compares these days to Quark these days. Or InDesign for that matter.