# 14.04: How to run Gimp in Single-Window Mode?

Tags: 14.04, gimp

I am running Gimp 2.8.10 on Ubuntu 14.04 (installed from the repositories). With previous Ubuntu versions [it was possible to run it in Single-Window Mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/136999/177437); this is no longer the case  with 14.04:

[image]

Is there any way to get this feature working on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: It works for me (gimp `2.8.10-0ubuntu1` from official repos).

Comment: Great for you muru. What did you do?

Comment: Nothing. Worked out-of-the-box.

Comment: Takkat, have looked into the image I posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even when running Gimp 2.8 in Single Window Mode we can still detach docks to a separate window if needed.

In case we had accidentally or from previous settings many detached docks we can reattach all docks to a single Gimp window by disabling (unticking) *Windows > Single Windows Mode* and then re-enabling it again. This will move all detached docks back to the single window.

Comment: Every time I start up Gimp docks come out detached. I then de-select and re-select the *Single Window Mode* and the docks get integrated into the image window. What a weird behaviour.

Comment: That's weird indeed - I suspect something wrong in your user setting, but have no idea where to look... you can test this if Gimp from you guest account behaves as expected, if so then this indicates a setting in your HOME is faulty. If the guest account is bad too then there may also be global settings somewhere...

Comment: @LuísdeSousa: here's another possibility you could try: In *Preferences* go to *Window Management* and check *Save windows positions on exit* (or in *Tool Options* then same). This will load Gimp with previous settings on next start.

Comment: I have checked in the various 14.04 systems I run and in all the *Save windows positions on exit* seems to be on by default.