# Layer and toolbox window doesn't appear when I reopen GIMP after closing it using the launcher

Tags: launcher, gimp

If I close GIMP with the x on its window, everything works fine.

[image]

But most of the time I have so many images open that I do not want to close each individually. In this case, I go to the Ubuntu sidebar, right-click on the GIMP icon and click quit

[image]

If I do this, all images are closed, but unfortunately when I start GIMP again, the layer and toolbox window are closed and I have to reopen them (Windows->Recently Closed Docks -> Layers and Windows->Recently Closed Docks -> Toolbox).

Is it possible to tell GIMP not to close the layer and toolbox window each time I quit it?

Comment: You can try using single window mode: http://askubuntu.com/questions/136992/how-to-make-gimp-run-as-a-single-window

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Use single-window mode:

> GIMP 2.8 introduces an optional single-window mode. You can toggle
>   between the default multi-window mode and the new single-window mode
>   through the Single-window mode checkbox in the Windows menu. In
>   single-window mode, GIMP will put dockable dialogs and images in a
>   single, tabbed image window. The single-window mode setting is of
>   course preserved if you quit and start GIMP again. Single-window mode
>   removes the necessity for users of having to deal with multiple
>   windows.

https://www.gimp.org/release-notes/gimp-2.8.html

Comment: WOW. This mode is so awesome. Now also all images are listed by tabs also. And I dont have to worry where the layer window is hidden or something. This is so awesome - thank you! Also good to know you disable/enable label/tool window by tab. So awesome.

Comment: Nevertheless, those windows should be restored. Can someone tell what Ubuntu might be doing here?