# How can I replace Photoshop?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, gimp, photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to Photoshop or Paint.NET](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3690/alternative-to-photoshop-or-paint-net)

I am in need of some good software that helps me replace  photoshop. In particular, I do several tasks involving **.psd** files, and I can find no way to make the GIMP do the job. Any ideas?

Best regards.