# which software is useful instead of photoshop in ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to Photoshop or Paint.NET](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3690/alternative-to-photoshop-or-paint-net)

I like to know which software is same as adobe photoshop of windows. from where i get the tutorials of that software. can I install adobe photoshop in ubuntu.

Comment: Duplicate of most of http://askubuntu.com/search?q=photoshop

Comment: You can try GIMP, or photoshop on wine / virtualbox.