# Is there any photo editing software like Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: software-recommendation, gimp, photo, image-editor

I want to blur images, edit photos and use layers just like in Adobe Photoshop for Windows.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3690/alternative-to-photoshop-or-paint-net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try out [Gimp](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp/). It is a photo editing suite similar to Photoshop that is cross-platform and open source.

Answer (score 1):

one more alternative application is krita .
you can get it installed by `sudo apt-get install krita`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can try Darktable http://www.darktable.org/

For install:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pmjdebruijn/darktable-release
sudo apt-get install darktable
```

Comment: Isn't darktable more like lightroom though?