# Are there any easy to use image editing programs?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there a Paint.NET alternative?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142/is-there-a-paint-net-alternative)

I want to crop, maybe highlight some of the picture and be able to save as jpg. I want a program that is easy to use.
I tried Gimp but it was way hard to use.

Are there any easy to use image editing programs?

I don't want a replica of Windows' Paint, or something that looks like it came from Windows, or something that is made for kids.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/136991/gimp-too-complicated-pinta-gnupaint-etc-too-simple

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Shutter [image: Install shutter]

It's a awesome program used for editing and annotating images.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

## [[Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/pinta) [image: Install pinta]

[image: im1]

> It's description seems to match your
>   desires ;-)
>
> Pinta is a drawing/editing program
>   modeled on Paint.NET.  Its goal is to
>   provide a simplified alternative to 
>   the GIMP for casual users.
>
> Features include:
>
> Adjustments (Auto level, Black and
>   White, Sepia, …) Multiple layers
>   Unlimited undo/redo Drawing tools
>   (Paintbrush, Pencil, Shapes, …)

It's in USC too so a mere `sudo apt-get install pinta` works too.

Comment: Well a program that can use layers isn't a simple easy to use program, I'm trying "shutter" now...

Comment: +1. first thing that came to my mind as I read this question :)

Comment: Yeah shutter. That was my first choice too.

Comment: Shutter is actually very easy to use, the screenshot isn't that create, I thought it would be more like gimp.

Answer (score 2):

## [[KolourPaint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVzpK.png)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/kolourpaint4) [image: Install kolourpaint4]

> KolourPaint is a simple drawing and image editing application for KDE. It aims to be easy to use, providing a level of functionality targeted towards the average user. It is ideal for common tasks such as drawing simple graphics and touching-up photos.

[image: KolourPaint]

Comment: I don't want a Ubuntu cpoy of paint I want real program, sorry

Comment: @Alvar: you did not add that requirement in first instance. This is a real program, I can open it and view its source.

Comment: It looks like paint in windows! :(

Comment: @Alvar: you must have had a very bad experience. Anyway, look forward, leave history behind you.

Comment: paint isn't that bad if you copy-paste a screenshot, but if you draw, then it's just huge pixels.

Comment: @Alvar For [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/150311) they are great. If you need more details, use Gimp.