# Gimp too complicated; Pinta/GnuPaint/etc. too simple

Tags: software-recommendation, image-editor, paint

I've been looking at a few paint programs, trying to find one that I can use for simple office tasks.

Gimp is nice when I need layers or cropping, but apart from that it is a total overkill. I know Gimp is aimed at Photoshop users and it is very powerful - but for simple desktop work it's too complicated.

Simple alternatives like Gnu Paint or Pinta are on the other extreme of the scale; too simple. They seem to be aimed at kids, not office use.

**What tool can I use for light office/desktop work?**

*update:* Features would be things like rectangular selections, cropping, save-as in different formats, scale, flip, rotate, paste from clipboard into new/existing image...

Comment: What features are you looking for?

Comment: @Kempe: See my edit.

Comment: how about shotwell or Jakobs suggestion

Comment: Pinta will do everything you asked in your update. Is there something else you need that Pinta is lacking?

Answer (score 2):

There is krita from KDE, that might be worth a try.

Comment: Yes, this looks very promising. Last time I tried it (a year ago?) it was pretty buggy and wouldn't save files. It seems to work better now.

Answer (score 0):

Try **gThumb** [image: Install gthumb]: It is lightweight, you can browse files and do simple edits to images as well as save them as tif, tga, png or jpg. It even has the possibility to edit a batch of images in one run! ([full feature list](http://live.gnome.org/gthumb/features))

[image: screenshot gthumb]

Comment: I didn't find a way to open a new image, or to paste-as-new-image from the clipboard (screenshot?). Is this actually more like 80% photo library manager and 20% photo editor?

Comment: If you don't want to use the inbuilt file browser you can open images via rightclick "open with". AFAIK there is no option to create new images.

Comment: It seems really to be more a photo library and than an editor. I used this until I installed GIMP 2.8 mainly for small edits on screenshots (which I saved on Desktop before) because it loads faster and is easy to handle. But since GIMP comes in one-window-mode I prefer that. Is it really that complicated for the features you mentioned?

Comment: I love gThumb, but I'm also missing the "paste from clipboard into new" functionality. In gThumb 3.1 (just tested), you can paste an image in the clipboard over an existig image, but I have not been able to find "paste into new" functionality. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try gThumb, Shotwell, Picasa, or really any of the photo managers available for Linux.

Comment: I heard that picasa is dropping linux support though

Comment: I'm not looking for a photo organizer... I am looking for an app that can open a single image, or accept paste-as-new-image, and then do some simple editing on that.

Comment: Google did drop Picasa support but they still offer a Wine wrapper for the Windows exe to run on Linux. I really shouldn't have suggested it since it takes some work to get it going, but I didn't think of it at the time.

Comment: The kind of editing you described though comes with photo managers. The only other thing I know to suggest is to try running Paint.NET through Wine. That's the simplest editing program I know of that falls inbetween Photoshop and the paint programs.

Answer (score -1):

[XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) does it all, pastes clipboard as new, batch etc.