# Alternatives for paint.net that can be used for pixel art

Tags: software-recommendation, 17.04

I used Paint.net until I switched over to Ubuntu 17.04.

I've seen Krita and Pinta, but they do not fit what I want.

I will need to be able to do pixel art as well as normal functions.

I would like separate windows unlike any other program.

I would like a program that is better than Paint.net and is more flexible

Comment: this question fits better to [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). **||** in this case i can link to an existing answer (although the question is different): https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/49323/9157

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative to Photoshop or Paint.NET](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3690/alternative-to-photoshop-or-paint-net) (Given your recent edit, this seems better than [Is there a Paint.NET alternative?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142/is-there-a-paint-net-alternative), which I had suggested originally.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gimp fits your requirements, you can get it in the software store.
It will allow seperate windows as well as pixel art

Comment: I have answered this question because Ots Wng has edited his question and it does not meet any of the questions requirement so I have just told him that Gimp has those properties.

Comment: This answer may be a duplicate, but it still answers the question, like I said Ots Wng didn't know that Gimp met the requirements, but I told him as an answer(because it still answered the question), that it did have the properties as what he wanted

Comment: @EODCraftStaff Some confusion here is my fault. The first dupe votes here (initiated by me) turned out to be wrong. The OP clarified that nothing there answered it. I should've retracted my close vote! As YoureSOStubborn clearly explained above (so I'm really not sure what your objection is about, now), no one had suggested a correct duplicate when this was posted and when you first objected to it. *Users aren't expected to refrain from answering questions others think are duplicates. Sometimes those other users are wrong!* Later, we found a better dupe target, and it was closed against both.

Comment: I had a Experience where I was Seriously Down Voted for answering a duplicate. (Deleted) I have no objection. Just didn't want to See Op down voted out of existence. I have upvoted the answer and deleted my Posts.

Comment: Thanks, I know what you mean when you think this answer is a duplicate, but because Ots Wng didn't know that Gimp met what he wanted